# How to create a MYSQL db to store date - price

Tags: mysql

I have different product and I want to store price for each of these depending on date...
For example,

```
product 1 - from 01/01/2017 to 31/03/2017 price 30
product 1 - from 01/02/2017 to 28/02/2017 price 20
product 1 - from 02/02/2017 to 10/02/2017 price 10
```

Then product 1 from 31/01/2017 to 02/02/2017 cost is 60

Now I create a "simple" db like this

```
id_product - price - date
1 - 30 - 01/01/2017
...
1 - 30 - 31/01/2017
1 - 20 - 01/02/2017
1 - 10 - 02/02/2017
...
```

Then this product have 90 rows, 365 for every years --> for each product...

And this with time slowing db filtering...

How to optimize db structure?

Comment: Why are there two prices for the range 2nd to 10th feb?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Although you only need to store the range start (or range start and range end if there are overlaps).  If there aren't overlaps, then you should have an index on (id_product,date), and either way date should be a date data type obviously. You wouldn't normally store a value for every single day - but the overlaps complicates things - in part because it's suddenly unclear what your PRIMARY KEY might be.

Comment: That's a very small table. Only 40K rows per year per product? This won't slow filtering *provided* you have the proper indexes. Without indexing, even a 100 row table will be slow

Answer (score -1):

This will be a very big table, however it's ok.

Maybe you should delete frequently some rows for better performance.

e.g.: you delete in july 2018 the rows of july 2016...

Comment: I think that's what partitioning is for.

Comment: That is actually a **small** table. Only 40K rows per year and product. With proper indexing there's absolutely no reason for delays. Partitioning is for really big tables, in the million-row range